# How to replace initial PHP variable with new value on select in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am running an AJAX call that passes a select option value(from a State dropdown) into a Wordpress query.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/inc/businesses.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {postID: '<?php the_ID(); ?>', postState: $("#state").val()},
    success: function(resp) {
        $('#results').html(resp);
    }
});
```

And here is partial code from businesses.php:

```
<?php 
require('../../../../wp-load.php');
$postState = $_POST['postState'];

$userState = geoCheckIP($ip);
?>
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'businesses',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => "ASC",
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $userState,
            'compare' => '=', 
            'type' => 'CHAR' 
        )
    )
);

// Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Basically I want to pass `$userState` into the query arguments on page load and then swap `$userState` with `$postState` on change of the select dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would work?

```
'value' => (isset($_POST['postState']) ? $_POST['postState'] : $userState),
```